# How to run multiple brew commands with one line?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, homebrew

I often run the following commands, one after another. I wonder if it can be done with one line?

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
```

Comment: `brew update; brew upgrade; brew cleanup`

Comment: @Barmar thanks, does `brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup` do the same? I remember seeing this somewhere.

Comment: Yes. That only runs each command if the previous one succeeded.

Comment: @Barmar thanks again, that's all I want to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run every command one after another:

```
brew update; brew upgrade; brew cleanup
```

To stop immediately after one of the commands fail:

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup
```

This way, if `update` succeeds, and then `upgrade` failed, the `cleanup` will not run.

Both will execute commands from left to right.

Comment: @StephenCarr We have different answers.  I suggested `&&` to break out immediately upon error.  I also mentioned the execution order of the commands.  You provided neither.  Also keep in mind, that this is not a race.

Comment: I think this is pretty verbose. It would be nice to be able to do `brew services start mysql@5.7 nginx php` or even `brew services start all`

Answer (score 1):

Easily done.  Just add a semi colon.  So....

```
brew update; brew upgrade; brew cleanup;
```

This is the basics of writing your own BASH scripts.  You can write complex scripts that are a single line.

```
echo thanks this is a test; echo ok here is new line, echo run another command here; ls; pwd; echo thanks i rock;
```